# Word for when you do something just because someone told you not to

Tags: emotions

Example, imagine someone tells a bald person: "You would be a terrible hair stylist; you have no hair!" Even though this person (the bald one) isn't interested in hair-styling, they decide to become a hair stylist JUST because they've been told they can't.

So, what is the name of that feeling?

(P.S.: English isn't my first language, I'm sorry if I spelled something wrong.)

Comment: The old fashioned word for it is *contrariness*.

Answer (score 1):

contrariness
The person who habitually displays this trait is sometimes called a contrarian.

Comment: This would be improved with a dictionary reference for the chosen word.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.